# Laravel 9: Converting image upload action to array for multiple files uploading

Tags: php, laravel

I have an action class that is reusable:

```
class UploadImageAction implements UploadImageContract
{
    public function handle(Request $request, $imageProperty, $image, $imageDir)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile($imageProperty)) {
            // Handle uploading lf_image
            if (!is_null($image) && Storage::exists($image)) {
                // Throw exceptions here
                Storage::delete($image);
            }
            // Throw exceptions here
            return $request->file($imageProperty)->store($imageDir);
        }
    }
}
```

I `resolve()` this class within a Service class, `handleAttachments()` method:

```
public function handleAttachments($request, $report)
    {
        // Handle Attachments
        $uploadImageAction = resolve(UploadImageAction::class);

        // Handle attachment action
        if($request->file('attachment')) {
            $report->attachment = $uploadImageAction->handle($request, 'attachment', $report->attachment, 'report/attachments');
        }

        return $report;
    }
```

It works with only one file/image, how can this upload action be converted to array?

I have a code block but it's not as clean:

```
$image = [];

        if($files = $request->file('attachment'))  {
            foreach($files as $file) {
                $image_name = md5(rand(1000, 10000));
                $ext = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
                $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext;
                $upload_path = 'public/app/reports/attachments/';
                $image_url = $upload_path . $image_full_name;
                $file->move($upload_path, $image_name);
                $image[] = $image_url;
                implode('|', $image);
            }
        }
```

I am integrating [Uppy](https://uppy.io) which requires this kind of conversion. Below is the HTML used:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3 class="fw-bold required">Attachments</h3>
        <p class="text-muted">Upload images related to the case</p>
    </div>
    <div class="DashboardContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Uppy configurations for `.DashboardContainer` class:

```
const uppy = new Uppy.Uppy({
    autoProceed: false,
    allowMultipleUploadBatches: true,
    debug: true,
    restrictions: {
        maxFileSize: 10000000,
        maxNumberOfFiles: 10,
        minNumberOfFiles: 1,
        allowedFileTypes: ['image/*', 'video/*'],
    },
});

uppy.use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
    id: 'dashboard',
    trigger: null,
    inline: true,
    showLinkToFileUploadResult: true,
    target: '.DashboardContainer',
    replaceTargetContent: true,
    showProgressDetails: true,
    height: 470,
    note: 'Images and videos only, you can upload up to 10 files.',
    metaFields: [
        { id: 'name', name: 'Name', placeholder: 'file name' },
        { id: 'caption', name: 'Caption', placeholder: 'Describe what the image is about' }
    ],
    browserBackButtonClose: false,
});

uppy.use(Uppy.Form, {
    target: '#reportsForm',
    addResultToForm: true,
    resultName: 'uppyResult',
    getMetaFromForm: true,
    submitOnSuccess: false,
    triggerUploadOnSubmit: false,
});

uppy.use(Uppy.XHRUpload, {
    endpoint: './create/new',
    limit: 10,
    formData: true,
    fieldName: 'attachment[]',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: share your form from where you are selecting multiple files, also dd($files) to check how many files are posting.

Comment: Question updated. Checking the console log, the files are "successfully uploaded", but not being saved in directory.

Comment: Added this for testing, it works, but have to convert it to laravel rules. https://snipboard.io/RJucDH.jpg